# ok to remove some error messages Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model as follows:

```
    class Greeting < ActiveRecord::Base

      attr_accessible :icon, :content, :name

      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :board

 validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :board_id, :presence => true
```

I don't want error messages displayed to the user if there is no user model or board model.
I have done the following:

```
  after_validation :remove_errors_for_user_board

   def remove_errors_for_user_board
    self.errors.delete_if{ |key,value| key == :user_id || key == :board_id }
   end
```

So basically I remove any error messages for these attributes.
Is this ok and is the best way to do this?

Thanks from a NOOB job.

Comment: It seems a bit counterintuitive to remove error messages when there are errors, especially since you actually need a user and a board in order to create a greeting. 

Edit (since I accidentally pressed enter): 
You might want to make sure that there's no way of adding a greeting without already having a user and a board to attach that greeting to?

Comment: There is no way of adding a greeting without a board but there is the possibility of adding a greeting without a user. So i took off the validation for the user.  And I build a greeting with @board.greetings.build(params[:greeting]). There is no way to get to the greeting without a board first.  I just don't want to display the error messages to the user saying there is no board as they won't understand. Maybe I don't need to validate this as there has to be a board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite understanding what you are saying. But if you are saying that you want there to be no errors if there is no user or no board. Then this will work…

```
validates_presence_of :name, :if => :board_or_user_is_present

def if_board_or_user_is_present
  board.present? or user.present?
end
```

Comment: This looks really interesting. Can I access the current board object or user object from within the greeting object?

Comment: It depends where it's set. If it's in your application_controller, no. You would have to pass it into your create as a variable. That'd be too tricky if you're having problems here.